# howto : form with multiple models - re-render form after errors (fields populated)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a wizard, saved in 3 models, so for input I used a form_tab with text_fields, radio_buttons ... it works great except validation : when I fail I drive back to my wizard using redirect_back fallback_location ... but my form is blank, the user lose previous entered values.

questions : 
- is it OK to use form_tag (I have 3 models and not straightforward recording
- How to 'save' or put back previously entered values ?

Thanks,

Greg

My return loop :

```
return redirect_to home_wizard_path, notice: @user.errors.full_messages.join(',')
```

or, for the same result :

```
return redirect_back fallback_location: home_wizard_path, notice: @user.errors.full_messages.join(',')
```

in my form :

```
<%= form_tag(wizard_post_path, method: :post) do %>
<div class="input-field col s6">
      <%= text_field_tag('nom') %>
      <%= label_tag('nom', 'Nom') %>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                      <%= text_field_tag('nom') %>
                      <%= label_tag('nom', 'Nom') %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                      <%= text_field_tag('firm_name') %>
                      <%= label_tag('firm_name', 'Raison sociale') %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

Comment: can you post small part of your code here. You may need simple_form
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

If your form is directly bound with a model it's in most cases better to use the form helper `form_for`.

To answer your question about repopulating the form and rendering errors. You should **not** `redirect_back`, since this will result in the loss of current values. Instead render the same page again. This will allow the form to have access to the previous result, and fill the form with them. This happens automatically when using the `form_for` helper (if you updated the attributes of your model instance).

In case you can't use the `form_for` helper and use separate tags instead, don't forget to set the values. `<%= text_field :object_name, :attribute_name, value: object.attribute %>` If the value is not set this will result in an empty text field, otherwise it will be filled with the attribute value.

There are some helpers that make form creating somewhat easier. For example [Simple Form](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form) and [Formtastic](https://rubygems.org/gems/formtastic). **But I would at least urge you to take a look at the Rails guide about forms first: [Action View Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)**

---

## Example

A good example, is the result of scaffolding an model. You end up with the following code in your controller:

```
class ChairsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def new
    @chair = Chair.new
  end

  def create # I removed the json parts
    @chair = Chair.new(chair_params)

    if @chair.save
      redirect_to @chair, notice: 'Chair was successfully' 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

With a `chairs/new` view allong the line of:

```
<%= form_for @chair do |form| %>
  <% if @chair.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@chair.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this chair from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @chair.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :chair_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to show case the use of Simple_form and create quick form for you. See adding other tags inside this simple form.

Add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

Run the following command to install it:

```
bundle install
```

Run the generator:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```

in users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
     @user = User.new
    end  

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.valid?

      else
        render :new
      end    
    end

    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:user_name)
    end
end
```

In new.html.erb.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= simple_form_for @user, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :user_name %>

        <br/>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, so I am rendering back to form with saved values

Comment: you can save them inside the if user.valid? i am yet to write code for save